# Expo Av alternative for loading audiofiles

Tags: react-native, expo, blob, uri, expo-av

I'm trying to load fetched sound from database. It has blob uri, so expo av cant read it.
What can I do with that and is there any alternative for creating audio playback, whitch can work with blob uri?

expo av error

[image: 1]

Comment: You could try getting the file with one of the forks of rn-fetch-blob and then playing it locally

Comment: @Abe, as i know, rn-fetch-blob implements native code, and so it cannot be used in expo based projects. Isn't it?